# Android - Dialog box doesnt show up instead Source Not Found error pops up

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I managed to successfully process an *HttpPost* of a *JSON Object* through **AsyncTask**. As you all know whole the coding goes in the *doInBackground()* method and afterwards *onPostExecute()* whatever is needed to show as UI goes there. Therefore, I want to show a dialog box with an OK button that the procedure has been successfully finished.

But I get that *notorious* "**Source Not Found**" run-time error while I debug/run.
Here's the link of the scrshot of the error I took :
[Dialog.class missing!](http://postimage.org/image/el7hz6gup/)

And the code is like this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
        if (statusCode==HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder msgBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
            msgBox.setTitle("User registration");
            msgBox.setIcon(R.drawable.confirmed_icon);
            msgBox.setMessage("Registration succesfully completed!");
            msgBox.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() 
            {                   
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScardsMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/
                }
            });
            msgBox.create();
            msgBox.show();
        }//if statement ends.       
    }//onPostExecute ends.
```

I know this is redundant and maybe a dummy question and asked several times in SO but I'm new to Android therefore I need furthermore help and information regarding such like issues of error encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're encountering this while debugging a stacktrace from a crash, you'll need to attach the Android source in order to see the code for built-in classes such as `Dialog.java`. There are a few tutorials online that show the proper steps, such as [this one](http://johnsenf.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-sources-in-eclipse.html).

**EDIT**:

The references to the Android source code are out of date in the link that I gave, but you can obtain the relevant Java classes by cloning from  the [platform_frameworks_base](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base.git) repository on Github.

Comment: I think information you gave me is depricated. The links found under that link in your answer are in-existent. I searched and found GitHub but not sure what to download from there in order to attach to my project/s so that I won't get Source Not Found problem anymore.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The source code appears to have moved. The approach that I linked to is still revelant, though; I followed the steps myself during this past week.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an error and only indicates that the source of the Dialog class cannot be found by the debugger. It should not occur if you run the code normally.

Comment: When I run it normally without debugging it after the process is finished in the background the app crashes by showing the "Unfortunately app has been crashed". I doubt that msgBox.show() is giving me the error.